# How to add validation for firstname and lastname except only characters with mininum 50 in Checkout page Magento2.1.7?

Tags: checkout

I want to add validation for firstname and lastname except only characters with mininum 50 in Checkout page for shipping and billing in Magento2.1.7?

Refer my Screenshot.

[image]

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the `checkout_index_index.xml` in your custom theme.

and add the below code for custom validation for firstname and lastname

```
<item name="firstname" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="letters-only" xsi:type="string">true</item>
        <item name="max_text_length" xsi:type="number">50</item>
    </item>
</item>
<item name="lastname" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="letters-only" xsi:type="string">true</item>
        <item name="max_text_length" xsi:type="number">50</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

Comment: I want to add validation only accept letter not numeric in first name and last name, please help me how to achieve this?

Comment: On registration page

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `checkout_index_index.xml` within your module or your custom theme.

and add the below node for the custom vlidation

```
<item name="firstname" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="your-custom-validation" xsi:type="string">true</item>
        <item name="letters-only" xsi:type="string">true</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

After that You need to create `your-custom-validation` rule.